# backbone fetch on a nested route

Tags: backbone.js

I have a `Sites`and  a `Positions`collection. Each time the user selects a new `site`, the `id` is sent to the `refreshPositions` method which is in charge of doing the `fetch` call.
The route to get the positions look like this `'.../sites/1/positions'`

`view.js`

```
refreshPositions: function(siteId) {
 this._positions.fetch({
  success: this.onPositionsFetchSuccess.bind(this),
  error: this.onPositionsFetchError.bind(this)
 });
},
```

So `refreshPositions` is called whenever I need to update the `positions`on the page and the `siteId` parameter has the id, I just don't know to tell fetch to route to something like `.../sites/n/positions` where `n` would be the `siteId` .

Sorry if I missed relevant informations for my question, I'm pretty new to `backbone`.

Comment: `Backbone.history.navigate('sites/' + siteId + '/positions')`?

Answer (score 1):

I see, so you are calling `fetch` from your `Positions` Collection. The out-of-the-box functionality there is to fetch the whole collection (every `Position` object) if you have a RESTfull api set up. If you want more specific behaviour from your collection, you can probably write it into the Collection object definition.

```
var PositionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.siteId = (options && options.siteId) || 0;
    },
    url: function() {
        if (!this.siteId) {
            return '/positions'; // or whatever
        }
        return '/sites/' + this.siteId + '/positions';
    },
    // etc...
});
```

Then, assuming that `_positions` refers to an instance of `PositionCollection` you can do:

```
refreshPositions: function(siteId) {
    this._positions.siteId = siteId; // or wrap in a setter if you prefer
    this._positions.fetch({
        success: this.onPositionsFetchSuccess.bind(this),
        error: this.onPositionsFetchError.bind(this)
    });
},
```